# Why knockout.mapping fails on some data-structures?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using knockout.mapping I try to map from JSON to ko-object. When trying to use more advanced solutions with mapping options I often got `Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function`. I tried to figure out what is problem, but I am still confused.

Lets say I have pretty simple model:

```
var data1 = { // works
  a: "a",
  b: [ 
    { b1: "v1" }, 
    { b2: "v2" } 
  ] 
};
```

Now consuming this model works fine like this:

```
function viewModel ( data ) {
  var self = this;
  var a    = ko.mapping.fromJS( data, { observe: "a"} );

  return a;
}

var vm1 = viewModel( data1 ); // works
```

I have two properties (`a` and `b`) in my model, but I need only `a` to be observable, while `b` should just copied to the viewmodel.

Sadly it does not work so well, if data-structure gets deeper:

```
var data1 = { // works
  a: "a",
  b: [ 
    { b1: "v1" }, 
    { b2: "v2" } 
  ] 
};

var data2 = { // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
  a: "a",
  b: [ 
    { b1: { name: "v1" } }, 
    { b2: { name: "v2" } } 
  ]
};

var data3 = { // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
  a: "a",
  b1: { name: "v1" }, 
  b2: { name: "v2" } 
};

var data4 = { // works
  a: "a",
  b1: "v1", 
  b2: "v2"  
};

var data5 = { // works
  a: "a",
  b1: ["1::v1", "2::v1"], 
  b2: ["1::v2", "2::v2"]  
};

function viewModel ( data ) {
  var self = this;
  var a    = ko.mapping.fromJS( data, { observe: "a"} );

  return a;
}

var vm1 = viewModel( data1 ); // works
var vm2 = viewModel( data2 ); // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
var vm3 = viewModel( data3 ); // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
var vm4 = viewModel( data4 ); // works
var vm5 = viewModel( data5 ); // works
```

It seems baffling that copying some structures works and other not. I understand, that problem jumps in, when there is multilevel hash somewhere in the tree.

Is this desired behavior or do I something wrong here? Why copying some structure works while other not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've succesfully reproduced the issue you mentioned:

```js
var data1 = { // works
  a: "a",
  b: [ 
    { b1: "v1" }, 
    { b2: "v2" } 
  ] 
};

var data2 = { // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
  a: "a",
  b: [ 
    { b1: { name: "v1" } }, 
    { b2: { name: "v2" } } 
  ]
};

function viewModel ( data ) {
  var self = this;
  var a = ko.mapping.fromJS( data, { observe: ["a"]} );
  return a;
}

var vm1 = viewModel( data1 ); // works
var vm2 = viewModel( data2 ); // Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

As you can see, in my repro I include the non-minified versions of both libs. I stepped into it on the error, and it's here, in this code:

```
if(options.observe.length > 0 && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(options.observe, fullPropertyName) == -1)
{
    mappedRootObject[indexer] = value(); // <---- THIS LINE
    options.copiedProperties[fullPropertyName] = true;
    return;
}
```

That line struck me as odd, because typically with KO you need to explicitly need to "unwrap" values if you're unsure if they're a plain value or an observable.

So I went to [the relevant source code on Github](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js#L474), but to my surprise, the above code from the CDNJS version *is not there*, it's different:

```
if(options.observe.length > 0 && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(options.observe, fullPropertyName) == -1)
{
    mappedRootObject[indexer] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); // <-- DIFFERENT
    options.copiedProperties[fullPropertyName] = true;
    return;
}
```

That line is the way I'd expect it to be.

Then again, [the most recent debug build](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js#L467) has the buggy/first version again.

Then some more digging, I see there's [issue #137](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/137) with exactly this problem. That issue ends with the same conclusion I reached: the fix is not included in the 2.4.1 build. There will not likely soon be new builds: as you can see in [the project's readme](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/README.md) this project is currently not actively being maintained.

Bottom line: you'll need to either work around this situation, or create your own custom build of mapping with this problem fixed.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is thorough and enough. I may stop hitting the wall with my head now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered defining a custom object construction? Details can be found in the [**advanced** section in "The mapping plugin" page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) in the ko documentation.

There are quite a few options contained in that documentation for different cases of JSON objects being mapped to/from.